# A long line of my python code isn't displayed well in a beamer slide

Tags: python, latex, beamer

I'm facing a complicated issue with the 'minted' package, i want to display my python code in beamer , but it occurs that a long line doesn't fit well as shown in the snippet bellow. I'm asking if i can adjust my latex code so that a long line of my python code return to the line , also if i can adjust the number of lines in a slide from 15 lines - as u can see in the image- to like 10 lines.

Here's my code :

```
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,allowframebreaks]
\begin{minted}[linenos]{python}


#paramètres de l'interaction psychologique du piéton avec son entourage (suggerés par Moussaid):
    A=0.5 # permet de considerer le caractere anisotropique du piéton
    B=1   # la portée de l'interaction répulsive


#paramètres de la force de formation des sous-groupes (suggerés par Moussaid):
B1=B2=B3=4 # les amplitudes des forces d'interactions
q1=q2=1    # q1=q2=0 s'il n'y'a pas un sous-groupe à former
ai=0       # décrit l'orientation de la tête du piéton par rapport à la direction de son mouvement
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gave me  the next snippet:

[image]

I hope if anybody can help me and i will very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `breaklines` option to allow line breaks:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,allowframebreaks]
\begin{minted}[linenos,breaklines]{python}
#paramètres de l'interaction psychologique du piéton avec son entourage (suggerés par Moussaid):
    A=0.5 # permet de considerer le caractere anisotropique du piéton
    B=1   # la portée de l'interaction répulsive


#paramètres de la force de formation des sous-groupes (suggerés par Moussaid):
B1=B2=B3=4 # les amplitudes des forces d'interactions
q1=q2=1    # q1=q2=0 s'il n'y'a pas un sous-groupe à former
ai=0       # décrit l'orientation de la tête du piéton par rapport à la direction de son mouvement
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]